# How can I link my Facebook App Profile Page to a Facebook Page?

Tags: photo, facebook-apps, facebook-page

We have a Facebook App which is launching tomorrow at 9am.  The App Profile Page is here:  http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=305816312768314

There's a banner on it which says these pages are deprecated, and I should migrate.  I would love to.  However, there's no link that I can find which will allow us to migrate, either on that page or in the App's settings.

We have a page which meets the requirements (same name, and is a Product/App category) here: http://www.facebook.com/CameraAwesome

When our App publishes to FB (it's a Camera app), and the resulting photo says "via Camera Awesome" the 'Camera Awesome' link that FB is generating still links to the deprecated App Profile Page:  http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10150842254209778&set=a.10150842250419778.510347.525564777&type=1&theater

Already read and tried:

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/02/01/how-to--migrate-your-app-profile-page/

http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/611/

http://www.hyperarts.com/blog/how-to-migrate-your-app-profile-page-to-a-facebook-page/

Would love to  know how we can properly get this fixed so that FB is linking to the App Page rather than the deprecated App Profile Page.

Any ideas?

Comment: Based on the explanation that you provided here, it sounds like you missed the deadline to migrate your App Profile Page. As of 2pm today, the via link should follow this logic:
1. Canvas (if you have specified a Canvas URL for your app)
2. Page (if you have associated a Page with their app). Since they missed the deadline to migrate their existing App Profile Page, they will have to create this new Page in the Dev App (under Advanced settings).
3. Website (if they have a Website URL)
4. Facebook Homepage (if none of the above has been specified)

Answer (score 1):

Your official Facebook Page may not be getting all the fans it deserves because users are accidentally Liking unofficial duplicate versions of your Page you’ve created. These missing fans cost you news feed impressions and clicks and ad targeting opportunities, or require you to waste time managing multiple duplicate Pages. Fortunately, Facebook now offers the “Merge duplicate pages” tool to allow you to roll fans from duplicate versions of Pages into your official Page.[image]

### Instructions for Merging Duplicate Pages

Go to your Page and click “Edit Page”, then click the “Resources” tab, and then select “Merge duplicate pages”. You’ll then see a list of any duplicate Pages that are eligible to be rolled into your Page. [Update: We've determined that currently, duplicate Pages must be under your control to be eligible for a merge. Those looking to gain control of community Pages or unofficial fan-controlled Pages that represent the same thing as their official Page should use the "Is this your business?" link or "Report: duplicate" link beneath the duplicate Page's profile picture.]

To qualify, you must be an admin of the duplicate Page, and it must have an identical name to the official Page. If you don’t see any eligible Pages, check back in a few weeks as Facebook may expand eligibility to similar but not identical Pages.
Reporting Non-Identical Duplicate Pages

The merge tool only works for Pages you control with exactly the same name as the official Page. Therefore, you may not find the duplicates you were hoping to merge with in the tool. Admins have two sensible options in this situation:

```
Report the Pages as Duplicates
Wait and hope that Facebook will allow non-identical duplicate Pages or those not under your control to be merged in the future.
```

**Note: This merge pages tool is currently working erratically. It may or may not show up for you when it should even if the pages are both biz pages and in the same category and have an exact name match. Unfortunately this is a FB problem and I encourage you to [contact them](https://www.facebook.com/KnownIssues?sk=app_4949752878) about the bug in their merge pages tool.  If it is present for you it works well, if it’s not present you may be out of luck**

Comment: This doesn't do the trick.  :(

Comment: @DonMacAskill didn't get your point